# PHP script only partial image download

Tags: php, http-headers

When a user runs this PHP script it is supposed to just download the specified image file but for some reason, it's only downloading it partially. It starts the download then stalls at 1,083 KB / 1,382 KB. The download stops after a few seconds and when I open the image, the bottom portion is grey/missing. This script worked fine on my old server but the new server it won't. I tried changing PHP settings and version but no luck.

```
<?php

            if (file_exists("test-download-image.jpg")) {

                header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Content-Type: application/zip');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test-download-image.jpg"');  
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("test-download-image.jpg"));           
                readfile("test-download-image.jpg");

            }



?>
```

Comment: Why is your content-type a zip? Please change it to jpeg

Comment: Same thing when I changed it to jpeg.

Comment: Is the image corrupted? Try to add a `@` before `@readfile`

Comment: The image looks good when I download it directly from the server. Adding @ didn't help.